# might also be scaring off sb

Tags: word-choice

> Record prices might also **be** scaring off traders worried about buying at the 
>   top.

What is the role of "be" in the sentence? I would just write "might also scaring off traders".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Might also scaring* is not grammatical: modals such as *might* must be followed by the base form of the next verb.

*Might also scare* is grammatical, and is possible in this context.

*Might also be scaring* is also grammatical: "be scaring" is the so-called progressive form.

The difference between *might scare* and *might be scaring* is slight: *might scare* is timeless: it would often be used if the activity is yet to start, though it could also be used for an activity which is already happening, or has already happened.

*Might be scaring* specifically refers to something which is happening at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Auxillary verbs are always followed by the first form of verb. i.e; if you remove **be** ,you'd have to be saying something like this, Record prices might also scare off traders worried about buying at the top. **Which is not apparently what you want to say**

Be serves that purpose

Comment: So, what is an exact difference between "might be scaring off" and "might scare off" here? In both cases we have prices which can be scary for traders?

Comment: Might also scare of is **Static**. Whereas might also be scaring off is an on-going or recurring action.